# Currency Plural swift doesn't allow configuration

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover, currency-formatting

I want to remove a dot (".") from a `NumberFormatter`, because an issue with VoiceOver that read 20.000 (dot is separator in spanish) as 20 instead of 20000.

In the following example you can test that only currencyPlural is the only `NumberFormatter.Style` that announce complete string for currency but ignore `usesGroupingSeparator` flag.

Example:

```
func formatTest(_ style:  NumberFormatter.Style, usesGroupingSeparator separator: Bool) -> String? {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_CL")
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = separator
    formatter.numberStyle = style
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 20000))
}


formatTest(.currency, usesGroupingSeparator: false) // "$20000"
formatTest(.currencyAccounting, usesGroupingSeparator: false) // "$20000"
formatTest(.currencyISOCode, usesGroupingSeparator: false) // "CLP 20000"
formatTest(.currencyPlural, usesGroupingSeparator: false) // "20.000 pesos chilenos"

formatTest(.currency, usesGroupingSeparator: true) // "$20.000"
formatTest(.currencyAccounting, usesGroupingSeparator: true) // "$20.000"
formatTest(.currencyISOCode, usesGroupingSeparator: true) // "CLP 20.000"
formatTest(.currencyPlural, usesGroupingSeparator: true) // "20.000 pesos chilenos"
```

Any idea how to fix this? Please don't post a response like removing dot manually because I want to use format for multiple languages.

Extra: Voiceover in spanish ALWAYS announce `$` as dollars so I need complete text.

Comment: In cases when you're going to use the output for VoiceOver, why not use a locale other than `es_CL`, that doesn't include a `.`?

Comment: I always use VoiceOver, accessibility is very important for us. It should be for all.

Others examples of Locale can be `es_ES` or any `es_* `

I only use Chile as example but we want to apply this for many countries.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the voiceover API, can't you specify an output format specificly tailored for it, while keeping the GUI element displaying the "correct" format as you have it here?

Comment: NO :( . This is an old issue with voiceOver. Apple only has accessibilityLabel and AccessibilityHint but are texts that you put for better description. [see apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app#3017290). For this reason, I want to find some way for configurate currencyPlural as other currency styles (I think it should be other bug of apple if it is not possible).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance: isn't `accessibilityLabel` exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: I want to put the result of formatted string on `accessibilityLabel` but if I put for example "20.000 pesos chilenos", VoiceOver announce this as "20 pesos chilenos". So for avoid it, I want to remove dot  on formatting

Comment: "I want to put the result of formatted string" Why? Why not use `"20.000 pesos chilenos"` for the UILabel's `text` value, and use something like `"20,000 pesos chilenos"` for the `accessibilityLabel`?

Comment: Beacuse VoiceOver announce these text as "20 pesos chilenos". Depending of Locale could use "." or ",".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207616/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-jorge-ampuero).

Comment: I am working on others tasks but https://stackoverflow.com/a/60914923/7410617 was more nearby response that I was looking for. When I will came back to this task, I will add maybe a better response using that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to remove a dot (".") from a NumberFormatter, because an issue with VoiceOver that read 20.000 (dot is separator in spanish) as 20 instead of 20000 [...] Any idea how to fix this?

Display the formatted number you want and make VoiceOver read out whatever you desire ⟹ you don't need to remove the dot that's on screen. 
The problem is that VoiceOver can't perfectly read the currency while there's no problem with [numbers](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#date-time-and-numbers).

A solution to your problem may be to **append the locale currency to the amount** (just for VoiceOver ) as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // Your function is used to display the formatted text.
        myLabel.text = formatTest(.currencyPlural,
                                  usesGroupingSeparator: true)

        let locale = Locale(identifier: "es_CL")

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = locale
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

        // Define the a11y label to be specifically read out by VoiceOver.
        myLabel.accessibilityLabel = formatter.string(from: 20000)! + " " + locale.localizedString(forCurrencyCode: locale.currencyCode!)!
    }
```

Even if I don't know a single word of spanish, I changed my device configuration to test it and, apparently, it works as expected.

Adapt this code snippet to your environment in order to keep your format for multiple languages and have an automatic VoiceOver configuration for your locale currencies.

Comment: Yes it was that I looking for. You need to add and blank space for join strings. Exists any way for use plurals on locale?

Comment: @JorgeAmpuero: thanks for the blank space I added in the code snippet.  About the plurals on locale, I didn't find other way than the one exposed here ⟹ that's the most appropriate workaround I found out for your problem. ☀️

Answer (score 1):

I have another suggestion, a more elegant way to solve the Voice Over situation, as I have been in the same place some time ago.

The problem with using explicitly the `Locale.localizedString(forCurrencyCode:)` method to translate the currency code in its name is that it disregard the value, that means the spelling for CLP 20.000 would be '20.000 Peso chileno', not '20.000 pesos chilenos'.

If you use the `NumberFormatter.Style.currencyPlural`, in the other hand, you can achieve the expected behaviour. To guarantee it won't read as 'dollars', you can add a modifier to the locale to constraint the currency you want:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currencyPlural
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_CL@currency=CLP")

numberFormatter.string(from: 20000) // outputs 20.000 pesos chilenos
```